# Download button not function

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a problem, where previous time, this code was working. It can download the excel file if I click on the button. But now this button is not working and I'm not sure which part is not correct.

I have two files that are used for this function:

```
<tr>
    <td class="col-md-3"><b>Template File:</b></td>
    <td class="col-md-9">
        <asp:Button ID="btnDownloadTemplate" runat="server" OnClick="btnDownloadTemplate_Click" Text="Download Template" CssClass="btn btn-primary" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

and

```
protected void btnDownloadTemplate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FileInfo file = new FileInfo(Server.MapPath("~/Images/ACCUploads/ACCTemplate/AppleCareDevices.xlsx"));
    if (file.Exists)
    {
       Response.ContentType = "Application/xlsx";
       Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=AppleCareDevices.xlsx");
       Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("~/Images/ACCUploads/ACCTemplate/AppleCareDevices.xlsx"));
       Response.End();

   }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint within the `btnDownloadTemplate_Click` method, and seeing if each line of code is actually being executed? My first guess would be that the file no longer exists at the path that is mapped from `"~/Images/ACCUploads/ACCTemplate/AppleCareDevices.xlsx"`. The best way to check that would be to debug into the code, and see if `file.Exists` is true or not.

Comment: In your browser press F12 and check if there are any error messages in a Console panel. If there are any, please post an error.

Comment: Did you added update panel? or added asp validator that makes the page's valid state is false?

Comment: Vlad Bezden: Uncaught Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: The message received from the server could not be parsed. Common causes for this error are when the response is modified by calls to Response.Write(), response filters, HttpModules, or server trace is enabled.Details: Error parsing near 'PK!b��h^'.

Comment: Elezar: I have checked the file, and this file exist. This problem suddenly happen in our production and dev in same time. Both using same code.

Comment: User2012384: How to do that? As i'm not very familiar with this coding, i'm just beginner.

Comment: User2012382 : from what i checked, we using update panel for this section

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the problem but it looks like the code has an incorrect MIME type. Try changing it to:

```
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=AppleCareDevices.xlsx");
Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("~/Images/ACCUploads/ACCTemplate/AppleCareDevices.xlsx"));
Response.End();
```

Comment: I have changes the code but the button not working also. I tried press F12 in browser and get error, Uncaught Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: The message received from the server could not be parsed. Common causes for this error are when the response is modified by calls to Response.Write(), response filters, HttpModules, or server trace is enabled.
Details: Error parsing near 'PK!b��h^'.

Comment: Do you have any HttpModules or response filters? Based upon the exception you are getting, that would be my guess.

Comment: Can you guide me as I'm not familiar on this.

Comment: Those are things that would be setup in your code and/or web.config. It could also be setup by corporate IT if you are in a company. To find out more about modules, check out https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398986.aspx. Response filters are much less common; SO has a number of issues around them that you can check out for more info.